# Search filter in jQuery treetable

Tags: jquery, html, treetable

I want to implement a search filter in my treetable. I am using the JQuery treetable library and this is what I have done so far, but it doesn't seem to be working. Anybody having any ideas why?

This is my HTML:

```
<table id="example">
  <tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Tree data</th>
      </tr>
      <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
      <p class="log"></p>
    </thead>
</tbody>
```

And this is the function that I have implemented for the search filter:

```
var $rows = $('#example tr').treetable({expandable: true});
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first, it should be `$('.search').keyup ...` instead of `$('#search').keyup...` .
second, i think, the better way is:

```
var $rows = $('#tree_table tbody tr').treetable({expandable: true});
$('.search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

In this way the head always remains.